# Start and stop multiple processes at once (Ubuntu)

Tags: python, ruby, shell, ubuntu, scripting

so I have a bunch of mixed scripts on my Ubuntu server which I would like to run all at once, keep the PID so i can kill them all at once. They are mixed ruby and python scripts, which shouldn't matter since it would just be a list of commands to run and save the PID of, I just don't know how. And would it possible to have the script as ./script start|stop|restart?

Thanks

Comment: Write an init-script for each of your scripts and preferably place them in `/etc/init.d/`. Take a look at `/etc/init.d/apache2` (or any other script there) to get a rough idea.

Answer (score 0):

have all scripts running from shell script

vi Main.sh

```
#/bin/ksh

MODE=$1

if [ $MODE = "start" ]; then
#get PID of main sacript
echo " Main PID: $!" >> PID.txt

#Run first script
./script1.sh &
#save PID of script one
echo "script 1 PID: $!" >> PID.txt

#Run second script
./script2.sh &
#save PID of script one
echo "script 2 PID: $!" >> PID.txt

and so on...

fi

if [ $MODE = "stop" ]; then

Total_PID=`wc -l PID.txt|cut -d " " -f1`
x=1

while [ $x -le $Total_PID ]
do
PID=`sed -n ${x}p PID.txt|awk -F ":" '{print $2}'`
kill -9 $PID
let x=$x+1
done


fi
```

this is just an idea...you can modify this according to your requirement and this may have some syntax error (as this is not tested and its pesdocode)...please correct it... you will run this script as

```
./Main.sh start
```

or

```
./Main.sh stop
```

Comment: I have no knowledge of bash, correcting it is not really something I can do I'm afraid.

Comment: This script would work if you just replace    ./scriptN.sh &
with your command to run script and change permission of Main.sh file to chmod +x Main.sh

Comment: The random "fi" is that any important?

Comment: yes fi is very important...it is indicator of closing if loop... in other words it is part of conditional loop if.

Comment: Will this run stuff like ruby script.rb in nohup mode and will I be able to use the console without closing after I ran it?

Comment: yes "&" sign in the end is indicating to run your command in background, you can also run main script like "./mian.sh start &" and you will have console available to use while this script will run in background.

Comment: What about it running when I close my console? Does it need some sort of nohup?

Comment: yes that time you will need to use it as "nohup ./main.sh start &"

Comment: Would I be able to change the name of nohup.out to something else? Sorry for all the questions, I just want to make sure I don't break anything setting it up.

Comment: yes you can see this [EXAMPLE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45913/is-there-a-way-to-redirect-nohup-output-to-a-log-file-other-than-nohup-out)